# Provided inaccurate end date during interview. Now they are proceeding with the background check

Tags: interviewing, job-change, notice-period, background-check

I made a mistake during interview which told the interviewer I already gave my resignation letter before the interview which previously I thought my resignation notice is 1 weeks.

After the company offer me a position, I tender my resignation letter and only realized the resignation notice was 1 month instead of 1 week.

Now the company doing the background check, and the HR indicated the last day of my employment is difference to the last day I wrote. What should I do? Will this affect me getting offer from the new company?

Answer (score 10):

Just tell them you made that mistake. That's all. Being honest is the only way out of this situation.

Answer (score 3):

> What should I do? Will this affect me getting offer from the new
>   company?

You should apologize for the confusion and correct your mistake.
You should try to avoid these types of mistakes in the future.

Only the company can determine if this will impact a potential offer or not. Anything else would be guesses.